# Getting jQuery value to use in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
$('#topic').on('change', function() {  
    var sel = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'text',
        url: 'support_question.php?info=' + sel,
        success: function(data) {
            $( "#divtopic" ).data("topic", sel);
        }
    });
});
```

I'm trying to use the value of "sel" in a php query statement.  How do I get "sel" into the "divtopic" div to use in a query statement??

Comment: Do you want to append it into the div?

Comment: Yes, that would work.

Comment: FYI, .val() and .text() are not the same

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using post, it would be better not to append `info` to the URL.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: {info : sel},
        url: 'support_question.php',
        success: function(data) {
            $( "#divtopic" ).data("topic", sel);
        }
    });
```

and then access it in your PHP via `$_POST["info"]`.

Also, it would be better to get the value of the option instead of the text that is displayed, but you need to assure that the value attribute is populated with the values that you need:

```
var sel = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. In my php I'm echoing out $_POST["info"] and nothing is coming up.  ???

Comment: Put `console.log(sel);`, prior to my code above?  What happens?

Comment: I have $( "#divtopic" ).data("topic", sel);  I'm not really sure what the "topic" is for.  Is that supposed to match up to something???

Comment: I don't know, I didn't write your code:)  What that is doing is adding `sel` to the attribute `data-topic` of the element `#divtopic`.  You are not doing anything with the `data` coming back from the server.

Comment: I expected that to come back at me!  :)  I have this in my html/php:<div id="divtopic" data-topic="mytopic">
         <?php echo $_POST["info"]; ?>
        </div>

Comment: It looks like you are mistaking what AJAX is actually doing. It won't automatically update your page as you have it written.  The output of 'support_question.php' is represented by `data` in your success callback.  You need to take that data in your success callback and do something with it in JS.

Comment: Urgh. I'm sorry, feel like I'm getting close to using up my "free advice" allotment.  :)  So I can't use whatever's returned or outputted in a query statement??  In my "divtopic" div, I want to use the value in a query.

Comment: @JenMason you can, you just need to use it in the php file that the ajax request points to, not the page from which you are making the AJAX request.  If the AJAX request points to the same page, you need to realize that it is a seperate HTTP request.

Comment: Okay, I was trying to use it on the same page.  I understand now that that's not possible.  So, I've created a new "support_process.php" page and trying to echo back the information and put it into the "divtopic" div.  Nothing.  :-/

Comment: @JenMason In your success callback put `console.log(data);` to see what the value is, if not you will need to do more work to debug your PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the value on your PHP page:

```
$sel = $_POST["info"];
//do stuff
echo $sel;
```

You echo'd it back, now use it as the `data` variable from your jQ success callback.